# ListView Divider like lines accumulate as I scroll list

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

[image: multiple lines appearing at the top of list view as i scroll]**multiple lines shown in red circle**

I have attached an image which shows multiple divider like lines at the top of list view ,i am not sure how and why they appear in my forsaken list view .They tend to appear only when i scroll the list.I have rounded the place by red colored circle.You also note that video thumbnail is blurred at the bottom because of the very same reason.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/white"
> 
<Gallery 
    android:id="@+id/gallery" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Gallery>       
 <ListView 
         android:id="@id/android:list"
         android:layout_below="@id/gallery"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
         android:paddingBottom ="55dip"
         android:divider="@color/listdivider"
         android:dividerHeight="1px"
         android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

<!-- bottom buttoms -->
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dip"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:weightSum="3">
 ......
 </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

my list view and below is the row.xml from which i inflate a view

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/white"
android:paddingLeft="5dip"
android:paddingRight="5dip"
android:paddingTop="10dip"
>  


<LinearLayout

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/greyborder_with_solid_white"
>  
.......
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i guess something went wrong in my layout xml file ,but i couldn't figure it out,i will be glad if someone helps me.

Comment: android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true" looks suspicious or the view might need a refresh (invalidate) at some point.

Comment: The lines appear when if i remove android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true",any other suggestions!!

Comment: Can you please post whatever code you are using in your getView? The problem is *likely* there...